# TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__

Tags: python, list, string-formatting

I have two list named results and p_results. I want to show those list values in table like if

```
results = [1,2,3,4]
p_results = [5,6,7,8]
```

I want something like this

```
1     5
2     6
3     7
4     8

        print('{:3}{:20}'.format(results, p_results))
```

running the code:

```
runfile('D:/4/2d.py', wdir='D:/4')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-59-1abb0c96f0c0>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/4/2d.py', wdir='D:/4')

  File "C:\Users\Rabinsen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Rabinsen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/4/2d.py", line 61, in <module>
    print('{:3}{:20}'.format(results, p_results))

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__
```

Comment: passing a list as parameter is more restricitive on the options of format. Can you create a [mcve], with the input and what you want to output?

Comment: `bin_freqs` (or at least its indentation) is almost certainly wrong; neither of your loops as more than one iteration, because you return in both branches of the `if` statement.

Comment: The key to asking a good question on StackOverflow, and indeed, the key to good debugging, is to isolate the problem. The error gives you a clue that the problem is happening in the call to the print function.

Comment: I have just edited the question can you check it again @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: there is too much code in your question. It's just a format issue. 2 or 3 lines of code are enough to reproduce it.

Comment: I want to get output with a table like structure.. one list as column and another list as another column like

Comment: now the input data is missing, and the expected data too;

Comment: check it again @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 10):

One trick is to solve the spacing part:

```
'{:15}'.format('{}'.format([1,2,3]))
```

For iterating over two lists:

```
[print('res:', i, ': p_res', j) for i, j in zip(results, p_results)]
res: 1 : p_res 5
res: 2 : p_res 6
res: 3 : p_res 7
res: 4 : p_res 8
```

Combining formatting and zipping gives you what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 8):

You can pass a `list` type to `format` (using just `{}`), but the formatting you requested isn't available. And the standard formatting isn't suited anyway, so...

What you want is each list on one separate column. You'll have to `zip` lists together, and iterate on the result to pass it to format:

```
results = [1,2,3,4]
p_results = [5,6,7,8]

for result,p_result in zip(results,p_results):
    print('{:3}{:20}'.format(result,p_result))
```

That prints something like:

```
  1                   5
  2                   6
  3                   7
  4                   8
```

Comment: Minor side-note: `zip`, like many built-in functions that yield `tuple`s, has an optimization to reuse the `tuple` in question if it's not referenced when the next value is requested. For a normal loop, this is only the case when you've unpacked the resulting `tuple` up top (or more weirdly, `del`ed it later). Avoiding the unpacking doesn't save you much (if anything), and if unpacking lets you use more meaningful names it's probably the better option. For performance no matter how ugly, `for formatted in map('{:3}{:20}'.format, results, p_results): print(formatted)` would get it. :-)

Comment: was thinking about `for args in zip(results,p_results):
    print('{:3}{:20}'.format(*args))`

Answer (score 3):

Based on @istvan solution, just wrap your list with `str`:

```
f'{str(my_list):15}{str(my_other_list):25}'
```

(Or if you stick to @istvan example:)

```
'{:15}'.format(str([1,2,3]))
# or
f'{str([1,2,3]):15}'
```

Answer (score 1):

if you still wish to do it with a single line, write:

```
results = [1,2,3,4]
p_results = [5,6,7,8]

[print("{:3}{:20}".format(*x)) for x in np.c_[results,p_results]][0]
```

That prints:

```
  1                   5
  2                   6
  3                   7
  4                   8
```

To be sure, np is for NumPy

Comment: using numpy for this is just overkill

Comment: As noted, This is just another way of doing it. Maybe someone is lazy enough (like me :) ).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to print  organized, with spaces of 3 for the first column, and centered with spaces of 5 for the second.

```
print(f"{list:INT}") == TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__
```

An easy way around this could be:

```
print(f"{f'{list}':INT}")
```

Run:

```
print(f"**{f'{list}':20}**")
```

Output:

```
**[]        **
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try `print('{},{}'.format(results[:3], p_results[:20]))`

The way you structured your `print` like looks like a combination of two styles,

`print(f'{results[:3]}, {p_results[:20]}')`

and

`print('{}, {}'.format(results[:3], p_results[:20]))`

Your attempt is

`print('{:3}, {:20}'.format(results, p_results))`

This is the root of your error, here in example reproducing same error:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print('{:1}'.format(a))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__

>>> print('{}'.format(a[:1]))
[1]
```

Comment: it doesnt work I want output like in tabular form ... one list as one column and another list as another column

Comment: lets fix that first

Comment: it works on another two list but not in this ... I dont why it isnt working

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend that you use Pandas library for that purpose

```
import pandas as pd
results = [1,2,3,4]
p_results = [5,6,7,8]
d = {'column-1':results, 'column-2':p_results}
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(data_frame)
   column-1  column-2
0         1         5
1         2         6
2         3         7
3         4         8
```

Notice that you have an index using **data frame object**

Also you can make new columns an operations, like for instance
let us create a third column to store the product of column-1 and column-2

```
data_frame['product'] = data_frame['column-1']*data_frame['column-2']
```

The result you get now printing is:

```
   column-1  column-2  product
0         1         5        5
1         2         6       12
2         3         7       21
3         4         8       32
```

Hope this helps!
Happy coding!